# Using an Angular Modal as an Alert

Tags: angularjs

I am still relatively new to AngularJs and I created a pretty generic Modal view and what I want to do is be able to globally use it in place of other current alert()'s however some of them will have different text and buttons,etc... what is the best approach to instantiating a global controller but setting different preferences for each one?

Here is my example:

**controller.js**

```
(function () {

        var test= angular.module('test');

        test.controller('modal', function ($scope, $uibModal) {
            $scope.modal= function () {


                var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
                    animation: $scope.animationsEnabled,
                    templateUrl: 'template.html',
                    controller: 'test',
                    scope: $scope,
                    size: 'medium',
                    backdrop: 'static'
                });
                modalInstance.result.then(function () {
                }, function () {
                    console.log("dismissed")
                });
            }
        });

        test.controller('modalInstance', function ($scope, $uibModalInstance) {
            $scope.cancel = function () {
                $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
            };
        }); 


    })
    ();
```

**Template**

```
<div class="modal-header">
</div>
<div class="modal-body" style="margin: 0 auto;" ng-controller="exportController">
    <p>Are you sure you want to continue?</p>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer btn-group-xs">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-click="open()">Ok</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
</div>
```

**Example of where alert() would be**

```
 $scope.launchTerms = function($event) {
                $event.preventBasick();
                alert("Launch Terms");
            };
```

**CAN anyone show an example?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a service that is a wrapper for calling `$uibModal.open()` then inject that service wherever you need it instead of `$uibModal`

Simple example.

```
app.factory('myModals', ['$uibModal', function ($uibModal) {
    // called from various methods within factory
    function openModal(template, data, options) {
        var modalOpts = {
            animation : true,
            templateUrl : template,
            controller : function ($scope, $uibModalInstance, alert_data) {
                $scope.alert_data = alert_data;
                $scope.cancel = function () {
                    $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
                };
            },
            resolve : {
                alert_data : data
            },
            size : 'medium',
            backdrop : 'static'
        };
        // extend options set in each use type function
        if (options) {
            angular.extend(modalOpts, modalOpts);
        }
        var modalInstance = $uibModal.open(modalOpts);

        modalInstance.result.then(function (data) {
            // always do something when close called
            return data;
        }, function (data) {
            //always do something when dismiss called
            console.log("modal dismissed");
            return data
        });

        return modalInstance;
    }

    // one type of modal
    function alert(type, text, size) {
        var template = type === 'success' ? 'template-success.html' : 'template-error.html';

        var opts = {
            size : size || 'sm'
        };
        var data = {
            title : type === 'success' ? "OK" : "Ooops",
            text : text
        };

        return openModal(template, data, opts);

    }

    return {
        alert : alert
    }

}]);
```

Controller

```
app.controller('somctrl', function($scope, myModals){
    $scope.successMessage = 'Way to go Jack!';
    var modal = myModals.alert('success', $scope.successMessage, 'small');

    modal.result.then(function(data){
        // do something with data on close
    }, function(data){
        // do something on dismiss
    })


});
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/yQeATtnxConC9c5t2KRw?p=preview)**</kbd>

Comment: do you have an example

Comment: Wasn't planning on taking the time to create one but added a demo link to answer. Very basic...just opens a modal and adds some text from the `alert()`

Comment: thank you I am still kind of confused on using them on a separate controller

Comment: confused in what way? modal controller or page view controller?

Comment: I am confused on how I can use this factory in different controllers

Comment: inject in any controller the same way is done in answer or demo

Comment: do I build the factory separate from the controller, like in another js file?

Comment: you are declaring app module twice . Works fine when remove second declaration http://plnkr.co/edit/INNsZgZcKc4lYUq1hPG6?p=preview

Comment: ahh makes sense. Final question what happens if I needed to use two separate templates for each button modal?

Comment: that's why service function has arguments so you can customize based on needs. May need several flavors ... I don't know what your needs are

Answer (score 0):

I think a good way to solve this would be to create a service. This way with only instantiating the service you can include the data you need in every new controller without repeating code. Note you would need to moddify the code to integrate with yours for your needs:

```
angular.module('test.modalService', [])
        .factory("modalService", function () {

            var ConstructorMOdal = function (scope) {
                this._fillModalScope(scope);
            };

            ConstructorModal.prototype._fillModalScope = function (scope) {
                this._scope = scope;
                this._scope.message= scope.message;  
                // Do your magic -> variables filled here will be present in your controller scope
            };

            return {
                ConstructorModal: ConstructorModal
            };

        });
```

Include the service in your controller and instantiate ($scope here and in the service are as an example, you can pass whatever you want and modify the service):

```
test.controller('modal', function ($scope, $uibModal, modalService) { ...
new modalService.ConstructorModal($scope);
```

Comment: can you provide an example?